# JavaScript BlockStatement confusion

Tags: javascript

```
{1 + ''} + 10 // 10
{1 + ''} + '' // 0
```

Why does this happen? Do BlockStatements return 0, and why?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Do BlockStatements return 0...?

No, [blocks](http://es5.github.com/#x12.1) return the value of the last expression within them. You can see this by just doing:

```
{1 + 8}
```

...in the JavaScript console, which will show `9`.

> `{1 + ''} + 10 // 10`
>   
> `{1 + ''} + '' // 0`
>   
> Why does this happen?

Because although the block does return a value, that value is not used. `{1 + ''} + 10 // 10` code is evaluated as two distinct items:

```
{1 + ''} // "1"
+10      // 10
```

...or writing those with standard indentation and semicolons:

```
{
    1 + '';
}
+10;
```

...and you're seeing the result of the second one, as though the first one weren't there at all. The `+` there isn't the addition operator, it's the [*unary* `+`](http://es5.github.com/#x11.4.6) (similar to the [unary `-`](http://es5.github.com/#x11.4.7), but it doesn't change the sign of its operand). `+10` is, of course, `10`; and `+''` is `0` because applying the operator to a string converts the string to a number, and `Number('')` is `0`.

You can prove that you're seeing the unary `+` rather than the addition operator by trying this:

```
{1 + ''} * 10
```

...which is really

```
{
    1 + '';
}
*10;
```

It fails with a syntax error because there is no unary `*`.

As Felix kindly points out in the comments below, for the `+` in your example to be the addition operator *(which would have ended up concatenating strings, in your case)*, it would have to be [between two expressions](http://es5.github.com/#x11.6), and a block is a [statement](http://es5.github.com/#x12), not an [expression](http://es5.github.com/#x11).

Comment: Thanks! I had initially been confused because `{''}+'a'` returns `NaN`, but now I've realised that it is because of the +.

Comment: That's not 100% correct: http://es5.github.com/#x12.1 *"Return the result of evaluating StatementList."*. It does not make a difference though as you a block is a statement and therefore cannot be used inside an expression (at least that's how I understand it).

Comment: @FelixKling: Thanks for that! I've removed the incorrect bit ("Blocks don't return anything"). And now I have to go digging into the grammar (which I don't have time to do at the moment) to understand the underlying reason the block and the expression following it are kept distinct and separate. They are, and I knew they are, but I don't know what precise part of the grammar dictates that... :-) It's probably, as you said, to do with statements vs. expressions.

Comment: Looking, for example, at [the addition operator](http://es5.github.com/#x11.6.1), the production rule is *AdditiveExpression : AdditiveExpression + MultiplicativeExpression* and a block is neither an *AdditiveExpression* nor a *MultiplicativeExpression*. I don't know if there is a single rule stating that statements cannot be used as expressions (the [`for` statement definition](http://es5.github.com/#x12.6.3) has an explicit rule for the [variable statement](http://es5.github.com/#x12.2), for example), but it at least explains why the parser treats the `+` in this case as unary plus.

Comment: @FelixKling: Cheers, saved me the time there. I edited some of that info into the answer.