# Why does {10 + '1'} + 10 equal 10?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JavaScript BlockStatement confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9803597/javascript-blockstatement-confusion)

Why does `{10 + '1'} + 10` equal 10?

I'm guessing the 1 doesn't work because its in a string but not sure about the rest.

Comment: I suspect casting an object to an integer yields 0, so 0 + 10 = 10.  What did you expect would happen?

Comment: but `{} + {} + 0` yields `NaN` gotta lurv javascript <3

Comment: `{10 + '1'}` is not an object.

Comment: and `[] + {}` yields an object

Comment: @andreas: No, it yields a string. `[] => ""`, `{} => "[object Object]"`

Comment: @andreas: No, it yields the string `'[object Object]'`. The array is converted to an empty string, and the object is turned into a string.

Comment: @FelixKling oh pardon, the string is `"[object Object]"`

Comment: First, please take a few minutes to watch this video by Gary Bernhardt:

https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat

I promise it has entertainment value, at the very least.

*It won't really answer your question directly but it should point you in the right direction!*

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This:

```
{10 + '1'}
```

is a statement block.  It's not equal to 10; it has <strike>no value at all in fact</strike> the value "101", a string (learn something useless every day :-). It is not, in particular, an object.

This:

```
+ 10
```

is equal to 10.

Try this:

```
({10 + '1'}) + 10
```

and you'll see a difference.

Comment: `({10 + '1'}) + 10` => Syntax error :-)

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant :-)  The point is that the parser is seeing a statement block, and then another statement: the expression `+ 10`. The block is kind-of irrelevant.

Answer (score 2):

This is because all code inside the `{}` is ignored.  The code in the `{}` is an expression, which is run, and then its "value" is ignored.

So `{10 + '1'} + 10` is just `+10` which is `10`.

Answer (score 0):

What you probably would like to do is:

```
(10 + '1') + 10
```

Do not use {} in Math - use ()

Comment: It may be a good idea to abandon string concatenation as well in "math".