# Javascript: When writing a for loop, why does it print the last index number?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, interpreter

When writing a simple for loop in the js interpreter, I automatically get the last value the index number (i, in this case).

```
js> for (var i=0; i<100; ++i) { numbers[i]=i+1; }
100
js> i
100
```

Can someone please explain why the interpreter works like that? I didn't explicitly ask it to print the value of i.

Sorry for the ambiguous formulation, guys, but I didn't really know how to describe what's happening.

Comment: __the js interpreter,__ which one is that?

Comment: Please don't post (a link to) an image of text, copy-and-paste the text itself into your question.  Thanks.

Comment: The book I'm studying from recommended this: http://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/firefox/nightly/latest-trunk/

Comment: If you enter an expression in a console, it prints the result of the expression. The result of expression `i` is the value of variable `i`.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I realize it shouldn't be done like this, but I wanted for you guys to actually see the behaviour of this interpreter.

Comment: It's basically running `console.log` automatically for the purpose of debugging your code.

Comment: We believe you. You don't need to "prove" it with a screenshot.

Comment: @Juhana Hm. So it's actually displaying the value of "numbers[i]", when i is 99, the last number in the loop? Okay, I get it now. Still kind of weird to do this even in a loop. I don't remember having this in Python's interpreter.

Comment: No, it shows the value of `i` which is 100. After loop 99 it incremented to 100, at which point the condition `i < 100` wasn't true anymore and the loop terminated.

Comment: So it prints the value which "broke" the loop, so to say? Edit: Just tested that - nope. It prints the last value numbers[i] takes.

Comment: @Jujana That is false;

Comment: @cristianm err, no. How did you test that?

Comment: Just wrote this: 
"for (var i=0; i<100; ++i)
{ numbers[i]=2; }"

It printed "2". It prints the last value numbers[i] takes before exiting the for-loop.

Comment: Well yes, at that point, but I thought you were asking about the second line.

Comment: See also [JavaScript BlockStatement confusion](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9803597/1048572) and [Using a block's return value in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8618270/1048572)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All statements in javascript have a value, including the block executed in looping constructs. Once the loop block is executed, the final value is returned (or `undefined` if no operations take place). The statement that is implicitly providing the return value "100" is `numbers[i] = i+1;`, as the final iteration of i+1 produces 100 and assignment operations return the value being assigned.

`console.log(hello = "World"); // outputs 'World'`

Now, this is not to say that you can assign the result of a for loop to a variable, but the interpreter "sees" the return value and prints it to the console for you.

I will also add that it is the result of running `eval` on your code:

`eval('numbers = []; for(var i = 0; i < 100; i++){ numbers[i] = i+1; }')`

Comment: Yes, I arrived at the same conclusion after a bit of testing. Thanks for the clarification!