# Explain why for loop behaves like this in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, console

Though I'm aware of closures and scopes. I need some detailed explanation on the following piece of code.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  i // no console.log
}
```

Output

> 9

Why would it not display from 0 to 9 ?
  Ran on chrome developer console.

Comment: Where is this output occurring if not in the console?

Comment: Statements happen to have a completion value, and that's what you get when executing them in the console. It has nothing to do with closures or scopes.

Comment: If you run that code in the console, it automatically displays the last value of `i` -- in this case, 9. That won't be the case inside of an actual script. If you just type `i=9` in the console it also outputs `9`.

Comment: Is the question "Why is it printing 9 on the console?" or something else?

Comment: I see some folks  voting down for the question !  Well I'm not a pro like some of the folks.  At least I'm trying to understand more that's all.

Comment: @manju4ever: It helps to make the question very clear. Your edits are helpful. I pretty much understood what you meant from the start (though it took some guesswork) but I can see how others would have been confused.

Answer (score 3):

Your question is a bit vague, but it seems you are asking why the output would end at `9`, instead of `10` (even though, in your example, you provide no output method).

---

Your loop uses the `<` operator to compare `i` and the `10` constant, which translates to "less than `10`". Since you are incrementing by whole numbers, `9` will be the last integer before your loop falls outside of the `< 10` range, thereby breaking out of the loop.

If you are expecting `10` as your final output, you can use the "less than or equal to" operator (`<=`) to compare `i` and `10`.

---

**Edit**

You've edited your original question, and the answer to it is best summed up in [another Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23446915/269970):

> All statements in javascript have a value, including the block
>   executed in looping constructs. Once the loop block is executed, the
>   final value is returned (or `undefined` if no operations take place).
>   The statement that is implicitly providing the return value "100" is
>   `numbers[i] = i+1;`, as the final iteration of i+1 produces 100 and
>   assignment operations return the value being assigned.

Answer (score 1):

If you're running that in the console, it's because the console shows the final result of the last statement in the program it runs.

In your case, the `for` loop gives a final value of `9`.

While it may seem odd that I'm talking about a `for` statement giving a result (since statements don't give results), they actually do give a result with respect to the execution of the entire program. This result is obtainable by whatever is executing your code.

Here's an example. You can do the same with `eval()`, which will give you the result of the final statement.

```
var n = eval('for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {i}');

console.log(n);
```

This will give you `2` in the console as the result of the program `eval`'d even though the only result could come from the `for` loop, which returns the last statement result of its last loop.