# The console of After Effects's Script Editor logs only the last object in for loop

Tags: javascript, after-effects

I have the following for loop:

```
var arr = [ "a", "b", "c" ];
for(var i=0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    arr[i];
}
```

When I call it in the Script Editor of After Effects CC 2014 only `c` will be printed in the console instead of:

```
a
b
c
```

Is this normal that only the last object of the `Array` is printed? What happens in the background? The loop runs normally like `a` then `b` then `c` and printing the last object only is just an option of the Script Editor?

Comment: Yes, as usual the result of the last statement is printed to the console as the response. If you want to print out each element, you should actually write that by calling `console.log` in the loop body.

Comment: @Bergi just simply `console.log;`?

Comment: No. *Call* it and pass the value that you want to get logged.

Comment: @Bergi it should be `console.log(arr[i]);`?

Comment: Yup, that. (Admittedly I don't know whether there's a `console.log` global function in After-Effects, I just assumed a usual JS environment)

Comment: @Bergi unfortunately it doesn't work. This Script Editor's console works a bit differently, it doesn't even print the error after I try to run it.

Comment: Ok. So what is your [actual problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377), what are you trying to do? The question in your body ("*Is this normal? What is happening?*") can be answered with [Yes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23446706/1048572).

Comment: @Bergi I would like to know that the loop runs properly. Does it go through to whole array, or just the last element of the array. When I code In other languages with editors like Sublime Text `a b c` would be printed instead of `c`, therefore I wanna be sure that the code works as it should and printing only the last object is not related to the code.

Comment: I don't see why Sublime would print anything - it's an editor. If you paste the code in your browser js console, it will run the complete loop and print the last element. There's no reason why it would not go through the whole array. Try to actually do something in the loop - like summing or concatenating the array elements and printing the result in the end. Btw, if you're just learning to program I would definitely recommend an environment with a `console` object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is this normal that only the last object of the Array is printed?

Yes this is normal behaviour for ExtendScript Toolkit (ESTK),

> What happens in the background?

I loops through your array.

> The loop runs normally like a then b then c and printing the last object only is just an option of the Script Editor?

Yes. Again.

If you want to print out things you need to use `$.write()` or `$.writeln()`. This will be visible in the ESTK console. You can find the more on the `$` helper object in the ESTK under "Help>Javacript Tools Guide CC".