# javascript unary issue firebug

Tags: javascript, loops, while-loop, firebug

I enter the following code in FireBug's console on Win 7 latest, Firefox 11:

```
var age = 26;

while ( age < 37 ) {
    console.log("You can join!");
    console.log(age);
    age++;
}
```

It spits out what I'm looking for but prints an additional '36' at the very end.   I don't understand why. 
Here's what I'm looking to do:
1. Check if the person is younger than 37 years old (they can't be 37 or older). 
2. If they meet the requirement it should print "You can join!"
That's it.  Why is it spitting out an extra 36 at the end?

I just started studying JavaScript and this snippet is not being used for anything, I'm just plugging code into FireBug for fun.

I'm new to stackoverflow, too. Thanks for the support.

Comment: I'm not sure why you wouldn't expect it to print a `36`...

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8618270/using-a-blocks-return-value-in-javascript) for some related info. There's some sort of unusable return value that happens in certain occasions. Basically you can ignore it. The final iteration is not happening twice.

Comment: @PeterOlson: I think the key word is *"extra"*. There'll be `36` twice in the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is how it behaves normally. By default Firebug shows the value of the last statement.

```
var age = 9;
var temp = 10;

age++;
age < temp;
```

You can see `false` in console. I guess it is because firebug uses `eval`. The following statement also returns the same.

```
eval("var age = 9;var temp = 10;age++;age < temp;");
```

Comment: Firebug inadvertently prints the value of the last statement? So it's not MY CODE making it print that extra 36 ?