# Why doesn't this crazy brackety Javascript cause a syntax error?

Tags: javascript

I was playing around with some Javascript snippets today and noticed that this code would actually run:

```
{{for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {{{{
  alert(i);
}}}}}}
```

You can [try it out for yourself on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xbdgH/).

Why does this run without any syntax errors? What do the repeated brackets mean? Does Javascript just ignore repeated curly braces?

Comment: I get the error "too brackety." Do you think something's wrong with my interpreter?

Comment: @Daniel You should disable some of the strictness options on jsLint.

Comment: Also, you might be interested in http://stackoverflow.com/q/8618270/707111.

Comment: I guess the point is "why complicate the spec?" - If someone wants to throw in tons of useless curly-braces, so be it.  Otherwise, you're requiring the implementers of JavaScript interpreters to check for unnecessary levels of block scopes.  Then IE would of course do it all weird and then nothing works right..

Comment: @MikeChristensen: Yeah, that's pretty much it :P But I can't wait for `let` (which will never happen - thanks, IE 8 and lower!), which will actually make arbitrary blocks useful.

Comment: It should work in C too, or Java.

Comment: @minitech - Yea, though in all my years of JavaScript development I'm not sure I've run into a need to keep a variable private within a block scope.  Personally, I like the language just fine the way it is :)

Comment: In what way is this "too localized"? Argh, people always want to close the best questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`{ x++; }` is a "[Block Statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Statements#Block_Statement)".

`{{{ x++; }}}` is a block inside a block inside a block.

The code inside each block is executed.  So adding extra `{}` around someting doesn't do anythng.

Answer (score 12):

It creates a new block, which is effectively useless<sup>1</sup> because JavaScript doesn't have block scope<sup>2</sup>.

<sub><sup>1</sup> This is a beautiful oxymoron.

<sup>2</sup> Yet.</sub>

Comment: I was gonna say something like this.  But you said it better, thus `+1`.

Answer (score 3):

Brackets-within-brackets is just delineated blocks of code. Your sample could expand out to:

```
{
    {
        for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            {
                {
                    { 
                        alert(i); 
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

which is silly, but fine