# curly brace in javascript

Tags: javascript, curly-braces

demo1:

```
{"aa":111}
```

demo2:

```
{aa:111}
```

demo1 result:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token :  (in chrome)

demo2 result:

> 111

how to explain these two demos?
tks

Comment: [More about blocks' return values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8618270/using-a-blocks-return-value-in-javascript) :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They're being parsed as statements, not expressions.

The `{ ... }` is parsed as a block statement.
The `aa:` is parsed as a statement label.
The `111` is parsed as an expression statement containing a number.  Since it's the last statement you're eval-ing, its value is returned.

The `"aa":` is a syntax error.  Since statement labels cannot contain `"`s, it's parsed as an expression statement (like `111`, but a string rather than a number).  Therefore, the `"` makes no sense.

You want them to be parsed as object literals, which are expressions.
Wrap them in parentheses.