# Why is iterating once more in console.log javascript?

Tags: javascript, console.log

i understand the loops i guess, but im surprised to see in console.log of firebug iterating once more.I expect 10x to iterate(0-9). Why the 10??

```
$i = 0;

while ($i < 10) {
    console.log($i);//the last time here should be $i=9, not $i=10
    ++$i;
}

// in console log i have(0...10)

while ($i < 10) {
    console.log($i);
    $i++;
}
// in console.log i have doubled 9(0...9,9) Why 9 doubled???
```

Thanks for you advice

Comment: Why are you naming your variable `$i`? That's PHP-ism.

Comment: [This doesn't double 9 for me...](http://jsfiddle.net/dU4Ey/)

Comment: Change your `console.log` to `console.log("$i is " + $i);` and see what it looks like.

Comment: More information in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8618270/using-a-blocks-return-value-in-javascript) about apparent return values from statements when the statement is the last one eval'd.

Comment: ...do `void ++$i` to void the result. You'll get `undefined` that way. Or after the loop, put a string, like `"done!"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you see is just the result of the last statement, which is `$i++` or `++$i`. If you directly type this statement in the console, you see a number outputed as well, even if you don't explicitly output it.

For example, if I run the code directly in Firefox's console, I actually see

```
10
0
1
...
9
```

The `10` is the result of the last execution of `++$i` and the others are the `console.log` statements, which are only executed after the code terminated (as it seems).

If you use

```
console.log('Iteration: ' + $i);
```

then you will see the difference more clearly.

---

That's also the reason why you see two `9`s, since the result of `$i++` (where `$i = 9`) is `9`.

Comment: OK, i think i get it :).Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I think the "10" and "9" you don't want you're seeing is what is returned in the console.